# How to use enum from typescript definition file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, pdfmake

I'm programming in nodejs using typescript.

I'm using [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/#/)
 and I installed typescript definition files for this library (@types/pdfmake)

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/pdfmake/index.d.ts

I'm importing one of the enums from this file

`import { PageSize } from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";`

and using it like this `PageSize.A4`

This compiles, but when I try to access value A4 of this enum, runtime error occurs

TypeError: Cannot read property 'A4' of undefined

Any help would be greatly appreciated

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-pdf-make",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && node --inspect dist/app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.1",
    "tslint": "^5.19.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/pdfmake": "^0.1.8",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.58"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

````
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "lib": ["es2015"]
}```
````

Comment: Please include your package.json and tsconfig into question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that type definitions are just for types. They don't change the runtime behavior of a module. So while TypeScript is happy with your code because the type definitions say that this module exports an enum `PageSize`, this falls apart when running the code because in reality the module does not export `PageSize`.

I would consider this a bug in `@types/pdfmake`.

This problem could be resolved in `@types/pdfmake` by making the enum `const`:

```js
const enum PageSize {
   // ...
}
```

TypeScript automatically inlines const enums. Inlining means the compiler replaces `PageSize.A4` with `'A4'` so that there are no references to `PageSize` left in the JavaScript code.

Of course this would require a change in `@types/pdfmake`. I encourage you to open a pull request or issue on the [DefinitelyTyped repo](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped).

---

Without any changes in `@types/pdfmake` the only option you have is use hardcoded strings:

```js
pageSize: 'A4' as PageSize
```

Unfortunately you'll probably even have to cast it to the `PageSize` enum, because that's what the type definitions expect.

Answer (score 5):

When processing an `enum` in a TypeScript **source file (.ts)**, the TypeScript compiler emits the appropriate JavaScript code to create an object which can be accessed at runtime.

However when processing the TypeScript **declaration file (.d.ts)** in your case, the `enum` is has been wrapped inside a `declare module "pdfmake/build/pdfmake"` block.   Inside a "declare module", the compiler does not try to implement the object.    Compare [example 1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=2#code/KYOwrgtgBAYg9nAygSwF7CgbwLACgoGEECCALADR5FHEDMl%201JATA0yQIwMC%20QA) vs[example 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=2#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBbA9sArhBAiADsAZolANYgD0ARmgJYTBl6EkhbwDeAsAFDy-wgA7NIngAxZMgDK1AF4JOPPkoCCAFgA03JSoDMmxdvjKATPsO9lARn0BfG0A) on the TypeScript playground to understand the effect.

This behavior is by design, because the intended use-case for declaration files is enable type-checking of code written in a separate module (typically one written in JavaScript.)

Let me know if that isn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

First your import is incorrect as pdfmake/build/pdfmake has no default export. 
You can use:

```
import * as pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
```

to get a reference to the module, but you will find that the module has no reference to the PageSize enum as it wasn't exported as Burt_Harris explained in his answer.