# Angular 11 and PdfMake. Error TS2345: Argument of type {...} is not assignable to parameter of type TDocumentDefinitions

Tags: angular, pdfmake

I'm trying to define pdf document structure accordingly to offical documentation of pdfMake in Angular 11 application. But receiving an error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '{ pageSize: string; pageOrientation: string; content: ({ text: string; style: string; fontSize?: undefined; } | { text: string; fontSize: number; style?: undefined; })[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TDocumentDefinitions'.
  Types of property 'pageOrientation' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"landscape" | "portrait" | undefined'.

75     pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
```

I have installed all the staff:

```
npm install --save pdfmake
npm i --save-dev @types/pdfmake
```

and imported them:

```
import * as pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
(<any>pdfMake).vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```

Code:

```
getPdf() {
    let docDefinition = {
      pageSize: 'A5',
      pageOrientation: 'landscape',
      content: [
        { 
          text: 'Some data', 
          style: 'header'
        },
        {
          text: 'some data 2', fontSize: 15
        }
      ]
    }
    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
  }
```

When I removing from the method properties definition **pageSize** and **pageOrientation** - error dissappear.
What else I'm missing?

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution after viewing some posts here on Stackoverflow. Problem was in using pdfMake library (enum types) in TypeScrpit (described by [lukasgeiter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1903366/lukasgeiter) in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773414/how-to-use-enum-from-typescript-definition-file)).

So, I've changed import of pdfMake library from

```
import * as pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
```

to

```
const pdfMake = require('pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js');
```

then installed **node types** by npm:

```
npm i @types/node
```

and finally made some changes in **tsconfig.app.json** file in your Angular app root directoty (add "node" in square brackets in line):

```
"types": []
```

after changes:

```
"types": ["node"]
```

That's all. Compiler finally starts understand all of content types in document definitions for making pdf in **createPdf** method from **pdfMake** library

Comment: This was the best answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, this did allow the code to compile, but we've lost intellisense.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast it to the exported type from the types lib.

```
import { PageSize } from 'pdfmake/interfaces';
```

and create your style like this

```
pageSize: 'A5' as PageSize
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that but its not a great solution. It throws a complie error with something as innocuous as {text: 'Tables', style: 'header'},